# Differentiate $f(x)=e^x\sin x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

> $f(x)=e^x\sin x$

$$f'(x)=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x $$
$$=e^x\sin x+e^x\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$$

That's what I got. But, my book wrote something else.

$$f'(x)=\sqrt{2}e^x\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{4})$$

How they had taken common?

Comment: expand out $\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ using the addition formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)=\sqrt2\left(\sin(x)\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)+\cos(x)\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\right)=\sin(x)+\cos(x).$$

Comment: It is little bit looking like double angle formula, isn't it?

Comment: I think that this is more general.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the formula

$\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\left(\frac{C+D}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{C-D}2\right)$

where $C=x$ and $D=π/2+x$

Comment: Transformation of sum of trignometeric ratios into product

Comment: That is not the most intuitive formula to use here, usually you would use the formula $\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b+\sin b \cos a$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Here I have $\sin x +\sin y$ not $\sin (x+y)$